# DNS+DHCP. Как правильно настроить временные интервалы для очистки устаревших записей?

Tags: windows, сервер, dns, windows-server, dhcp

Имеются сервер DHCP и DNS на Windows Server. Как правильно настроить временные интервалы для очистки устаревших записей?

Возникает ситуация когда две A записи (динамические) существуют на один IP адрес.

Текущие настройки:
Аренда DHCP - 1 день
DNS сервер (Период очистки) - 7 дней
Зона (Интервал блокирования) - 4 дня
Зона (Интервал обновления) - 4 дня

Спасибо заранее